# Where is the "AJAX-enabled WCF Service"？

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2008, wcf

I have installed Visual Studio 2008 and patch it with SP1. However, I cannot find the "AJAX-enabled WCF Service" in my New Project dialog. Does any more patches should be added to make the "AJAX-enabled WCF Service" template appear?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552.aspx

Basically it's not in the New Project dialog. It's in the New Item dialog.